# creating a 'users' and 'friends' relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

```
_________          ____________
| users |          | friends  |
|_______|          |__________|
| id    |          | id_user1 |
| nick  |          | id_user2 |
|_______|          |__________|
```

But if I try to **join** them together, like

```
Alter table friends add Foreign Key (id_user1) references users (id) on delete  restrict on update  restrict;
Alter table friends add Foreign Key (id_user2) references users (id) on delete  restrict on update  restrict;
```

I get an `Identical attribute name "id" in entity "friends"` **error**. How would I do this ?

Comment: This is not a `MySQL` error. Are you using a visual tool to create the relationships?

Comment: When you say join, you mean joining two tables by SELECT/WHERE statement or creating Foreign Key relationship between those two tables.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE friends (id_user1 INT NOT NULL, id_user2 INT NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Alter table friends add Foreign Key (id_user1) references users (id) on delete  restrict on update  restrict;
Alter table friends add Foreign Key (id_user2) references users (id) on delete  restrict on update  restrict;
```

Comment: Hmm, changing the engine from MyISAM to InnoDB fixed it. Thanks

Comment: `MyISAM` does not support referential integrity.